# UART doesn't work with ADC enabled

Tags: stm32, uart, hal

I'm trying to send some data through UART using DMA. I'm also using DMA to control ADC and DAC. When ADC is enabled and I try to send data I get a HardFault error. The HardFault occurs exactly during execution of HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2) at the line: `uint32_t isrflags = READ_REG(huart->Instance->ISR);`  . When I stop the ADC the problem disappears but I can't understand why?

````
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{

}

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    if (i<2048)
    {
        FFT_buffer_in[i] = (3.3*analogInput)/4095;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
        doFFT();
    }

}
int main(void)
{
      uint8_t MSG[] = "yo waddup ";


  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_DAC1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

   arm_rfft_fast_init_f32(&fft_handler, 2048);

   HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, &analogInput, 1);
   HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)Wave_LUT, 128, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
   HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
   HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);

  while (1)
  {
  //HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1); -- only if I uncomment this, the UART_Transmit works

  HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2, MSG, sizeof(MSG));
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);

    HAL_Delay(500);

  }
 ```
````

Comment: You are not supposed to call `HAL_UART_IRQHandler`. It will be called by the interrupt handler.

Comment: If I don't call it manually, the HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback never executes - don't know why. Also when I don't call this IRQHandler the UART_Transmit sends data only once instead of sending data every 500ms.

Comment: You do call it directly. It's right there in the code of your question. And if `HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback` is not called, temporarily remove the DAC and ADC stuff and work on this issue until it's solved.

Comment: You're supposed to create a `UART2_IRQHandler()` function which calls `HAL_UART_IRQHandler()` (or it might be `USART2_IRQHandler()`, depending on your specific micro which you haven't shared with us). Check your project's assembler startup file (startup_stm_something-or-the-other.s) for the correct function name - it should have all the xxx_IRQHandler function names listed there.

Comment: By far the most likely cause of a hardfault on that like of code is that your `huart2` uart 'handle' structure has been accidentally overwritten - in particular the `Instance` member which is supposed to hold a pointer to the UART's register set. My best guess is that you have not correctly configured the ADC DMA correctly, and the DMA is doing a kind of 'buffer overflow' and writing to that region of memory. Show us the code where you configure the ADC DMA & the buffer (array) you're DMAing into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. It didn't call the USART2_IRQHanlder() because I didn't enable USART global interrupts. That didn't fix the whole problem though. UART Transmit still didn't work properly - it was in BUSY state after sending 1 message. I followed the code and found why - turns out the HAL_Delay(500) affected the memory where the state was stored and that's why the state value was incorrect. Thanks for all your input, it helped me follow the problem to its root.